# Loading more rows in Power Bi than theirs is

Tags: mysql, database, powerbi, dax

My query give result sth  like 26.000 rows. I can easy upload it on Power Bi . But when I tried to use simple query that return previous row `try #"Added Index" { [Index] -1 } [OrderID] otherwise null`  I got stucked on "Loading 58.000 rows" and it still going up and do not want to stop. Did I make some mistake in query?

[image]